# Number of real roots of $f ' ( x )$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, roots

Let $$f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)^3(x-c)^5(x-d)^7 $$
where $a,b,c,d$
are  real  numbers  with
$a < b < c < d$
.  Thus $ f
(
x
)$ has $16$ real roots counting multiplicities and among them $4$ are
distinct from each other.  Consider
$f
'
(
x
)$, i.e.  the derivative of
$f
(
x
)$.  Find the following:
$(i)$  the  number  of  real  roots  of
$f
'
(
x
)$,  counting  multiplicities,
$(ii)$  the  number  of
distinct
real roots of
$f
'
(
x
)$.

---

This is a polynomial of degree $16$ hence the derivative will be of degree $15$ and hence it will have $15$ roots. But are they real ?
How to find distinct real roots ? Rolle's theorem tells only about existence of root.

Comment: How about finding $f'(x)$ explicitly?

Comment: Hint:  $12$ of the roots are obvious (every multiple root of $f(x)$ is a zero of $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

If $p(x) = (x-\lambda)^n q(x)$ then from the product rule: 
 
$p'(x) = n(x-\lambda)^{n-1}q(x)+(x-\lambda)^nq'(x)=(x-\lambda)^{n-1}\left[nq(x)+(x-\lambda)q'(x)\right]$ 
This shows that if $\lambda$ is a root of $p(x)$ of multiplicity $n>1$, then $\lambda$ is also a root of $p'(x)$ with multiplicity $n-1$. 
This gets you 2 + 4 + 6 = 12 real roots from b, c, and d, and the other 3 come from Rolle's theorem. 
To summarize: 15 real roots, 6 of which are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider the following: A root of some polynomial $P$ with multiplicity $n$ is a root of its derivative $P'$ with multiplicity $n-1$. Hence here, $b$, $c$ and $d$ wil be distinct real roots with respective multiplicities $2$,$4$,$6$, accounting for $12$ of the $15$ roots of $f'$. dividing $f'$ by $(x-b)^{2}(x-c)^{4}(x-d)^{6}$ will give you a degree $3$ polynomial, and ascertaining the v

Comment: ascertaining the nature of its roots can be done by calculating the disriminant